# Error: Could not find or load main class in intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner in Java and am trying to run my code using IntelliJ that I just installed as my IDE with JDK 1.7.  The following piece of code keeps does not even compile and keeps giving me the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class libTest
```

### Code

```
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.*;

class book {

    private String name = "trial";
    private int bookCode=1;
    private int issued=0;

     public void Issue(){
         if(issued==0) {
             issued=1;
             System.out.println("You have succesfully issued the book");
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("The book is already issued. Please contact the librarian for further details");
         }
    }

    public int checkCode() {
        return bookCode;
    }

    String readName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        name=newName;
    }

    public void setBookCode(int newCode){
        bookCode=newCode;
    }
}

class library {
    private ArrayList books=new ArrayList();

    public void getList(){
        for(int bk:books){
            String bName=books(bk).readName();
            System.out.println((bk+1)+")  "+bName);
        }
    }
}

public class libTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        library newLib= new library();
        System.out.println("code working");
   }
}
```

Is there any change that i have to make in the compiler settings?? Or is it the code.

Comment: What's the name of the source file?  Is it `libTest.java`?

Comment: `import java.lang...` This happens automatically for classes  in the `lang` package.

Comment: As mentioned by QuantumMechanic, your main class needs to be in a file named exactly like it.  So libTest needs to be in a java file named libTest.java, otherwise the java compiler will complain.  Also, did you create the source through IDEA, or did you create a new IDEA project over existing source?

Comment: tried importing java.lang made no difference

Comment: they are identical. Is there any other reason why such a error should get flagged?

Comment: There are 2 compilation errors in the `library` class.  Neither of them is the 'not found' error you quoted.  Is that the *actual* copy/pasted code being used?  Are the classes in separate files?  Are they in separate packages (directories on the file-system).  My comment about 'automatic' was meant to indicate 'remove the `lang` imports'. ;)

Comment: *"There are 2 compilation errors in the library class."* Specifically `I:\libTest.java:40: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: int
        for(int bk:books){
                   ^
I:\libTest.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method books(int)
location: class library
            String bName=books(bk).readName();
                         ^
2 errors`

Comment: i realized..i had commented the two errors during run time..even when i dont comment the errors, it still does not flag them as errors..il try it on a separate compiler.

Comment: i created the source through the IDEA

Comment: Please zip and share your IntelliJ IDEA project so that we can check what is the problem.

Answer (score 281):

This might help:

1) "Build" menu -> "`Rebuild Project`".
Sometimes Intellij doesn't rewrite the classes because they already exist, this way you ask Intellij to rewrite everything.

2) "Run" menu -> "`Edit configuration`" -> delete the profile -> add back the profile ("Application" if it's a Java application), choose your main class from the "Main Class" dropdown menu.

3)"Build" menu -> "`Rebuild Project`".

Comment: I had a brand new project in IntelliJ and it would not run. `Rebuild Project` worked for me!

Comment: 2nd option worked for me. But delete the configuration profile and then, right click your class --> run

Comment: `"Build" menu -> "Rebuild Project` - did the job! Thanks

Comment: For me above answer has worked in the past, but this time what worked wasan additional step to above answer ->  "open the main class, right click -> run"

Comment: The first option `rebuild project` worked for my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I removed the .idea, .mvn and other target directories then restarted IntelliJ. Went to event log , added project as a Maven project and then followed the steps mentioned by @Kishore over here. It is working now.

Comment: What worked for me was to close intellij and removing `.idea` and `.mvn` folder, and start intellij again with the source code folder. Rebuild project and now run you code by right click on class's main method and run

Comment: Rebuild and then -> restarting <-  IntelliJ did the trick.

Comment: I got this error when I copied VM arguments from a Web page, which had special characters. I had no clue what was happening.  Had to use ANSI Encoding in my Notepad++ to view those special characters. Hope this tip helps someone not to go crazy for a day to find the solution, like me :-)

Answer (score 268):

If none of the above answers worked for you, just close your IntelliJ IDE and remove the IntelliJ IDE file and folder from the root of your project:

```
rm -rf .idea *.iml
```

Then, open the project with IntelliJ. It should work now.

Comment: This worked for me.  I also re-imported my project into IntelliJ, but for the "Group Modules" option, I used "using qualified names" (instead of "using explicit module groups".

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` folder always resolves all the problems with JetBrains' IDEs :)

Comment: this worked for me too, I'm a big fan of Intellij, but they must learn to do simple things too.

Comment: This worked but i had to set the project settings again.

Comment: I needed to do this when I change the version of my dependencies. Thanks +1

Comment: This fixes almost every problem with IDEA as others have pointed out. My problem was some discrepancies between the actual contents of the project and the .iml file after checking out a branch that is quite old. Since we gitignore .iml files, it sits there and waits while you switch branches, and breaks where you least expected.

Comment: IntelliJ and most of the IDE's produced by the same company are truly great, but sometimes you wish they did not exist and this is one of those times

Answer (score 89):

For me the solution was to fix the output directory under project settings.  Before I was using just "target" for the Project compiler output.  Instead I updated it to have a full path e.g. D:\dev\sigplusjava2_68\target
[image]

Comment: It's possible that my solution here is actually a subtle variation of  @Ehsan's answer below.  Perhaps by specifying the target directory it gives it a new location wherein to compile all the objects essentially performing the same work that a `Rebuild Project` does.

Comment: @UncleIroh If it did the same work, rebuilding + reading the config. would have fixed the issue initially. It didn't, but your solution did.

Answer (score 54):

I had this problem and I tried everything under the sun that I could think of and on this site.

None of my Java classes were being picked up after I pulled from a remote branch. All the classes had red Js by their names in the Project Hierarchy, not blue Cs.

In the end, I tried to follow this tutorial and a few steps in tried something not described and fixed the issue:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Here's what I did:

1. Goto File | Project Structure, or press Crtl+Shift+Alt+S
2. Select Modules under the Project Settings section.
3. In the Sources tab click Sources on the 'Mark as:' line.
4. Click the Apply button.

For some reason, all my classes then had blue C's.

Someone with a better understanding of how IntelliJ and/or IDE's might be able to explain the phenomenon, but all I know is now it can see all the classes and more importantly the main one, and run.

Comment: This only worked for me after I closed Intellij, removed the .idea folder then reopened Intellij and follow the steps above.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. Works fine when launching with gradle, but you need to configure sources to run as an application

Answer (score 39):

Invalidate cache and restart your IntelliJ, it worked for me.

[image: File menu → Invalidate Caches / Restart... option]

Answer (score 19):

Explicitly creating an `out` folder and then setting the output path to `C:\Users\USERNAME\IdeaProjects\PROJECTNAME\out`

[image: LIKE THIS]

seemed to work for me when just `out`, and expecting IntelliJ to make the folder wouldn't.

---

Also try having IntelliJ make you a new run configuration:

Find the previous one by clicking

[image: ![Edit Configurations]

then remove it

[image]

and hit okay.

**Now, (IMPORTANT STEP) open the class containing your main method.** This is probably easiest done by clicking on the class name in the left-hand side Project Pane.

Give 'er a <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and you should get a

[image: THIS]

Now hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>!!

*Tadah??*
*(Did it work?)*

Comment: The run configuration thing works, especially if you moved the `main()` function from the `class Main` to some other class. In that case, edit the run config as shown above and change the value of 'Main class' to your class name(fully qualified).

Comment: I have only "Edit configuration" option, doesn't work for me (

Answer (score 13):

File > Project Structure > Modules > Mark "src" folder as sources.
This should fix the problem. Also check latest language is selected so that you don't have to change code or do any config changes.
[image]

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Answer (score 10):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I was just stumbling over this issue and thought my findings might help others. As pointed out, the error message is basically a result of the out folder. That's because, when you're trying to run the program, it compiles the code first, and puts the compiled result to the out location, and then it tries to load the compiled code from the out location. If the compiled code is not in the location expected, you'll get the error.

The point I'm particularly wanting to share is that some times, the code is not compiled (built), even though your run configuration specifies "Build" in the "Before launch" section of the configuration panel.

When can this happen? 
One situation that can cause this to happen is if you're using modules and you manually delete the module out directory. For example, if I have a module named "foo", there should be a directory named foo under out/production. If you manually delete it, the build system may not know that it needs to be rebuilt.

Even worse, if you select Build | Build module 'foo', it still may not rebuild the module. If that's the case, you should select a file in the module, for example 'bar.java' and then select Build | Recompile 'bar.java'. Now the out directory out/production/foo should be restored.

Since IntelliJ typically knows about any changes going on, this surprised me, and took me a little time to figure out, so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 9):

I had to mark the "src" folder as "Sources". After restarting IntelliJ and rebuilding the project I could run the project without further issues (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86qrp.png)).
Edit: You can access the "Project Structure" tab via File->Project Structure or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S.

Comment: If you (like me) don't have a 'sources' tab, then you should add a new module (click the green +) and select your main folder as the source.  Nothing will be overwritten, and the src folder will turn blue.

Comment: it worked after marking "src" folder as Sources and rebuild

Answer (score 7):

**Check your class module** : I have encountered this problem with intellij :
I have a maven multi-module project, the problem is that i runing a class which not exist the  module within the configuration, so my problem is fixed by setting the right module ("edit configuration" -> "use class of module")

may this help you

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!
Something had probably gone wrong when installing an upgrade of IntelliJ or the Scala plugin. Afterwards you get this strange problem. Very annoying and time consuming. Hopefully JetBrains finds a resolution.

Comment: This worked for me, but the option is now called "Inherit project compile output path".

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem when my Java class was under `src/main/kotlin`. After I moved it to `src/main/java`, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced such problems when the class is in the default folder, i.e. when the class does not declare a package.

So I guess using a package statement (eg. `package org.me.mypackage;`) on top of the class should fix it.

Comment: do i replicate that line of code??..how do i modify it in case i have to??

Comment: Just use a package name of your own, like this : `package org.confused.mailman;`

Comment: Well, the package statement has to match where the IDE has put the file.  If the IDE didn't put the file in sourceBase/`org/confused/mailman` then adding that package line isn't going to help.

Comment: I guess IDE will guide on this, and automatically fix this, if the recommended fix is selected.

Comment: not helping :/..the IDE does not seem to be bothered with any of the changes i make..it throws the above error and sits backs and relaxes

Answer (score 6):

Open Modules Tab (Press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S). I had two modules under one project. I've solved the problem after removing the second redundant module (see screenshot).[image]

Answer (score 5):

After creating your project in intelliJ, try running the following command:

```sh
mvn package
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run the maven command on the pom.xml file in your project directory:

`mvn clean install`

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the hacks suggested here - to no avail. At the end I have simply created a new Maven application and manually copied into it - one by one - the pom.xml and the java files and resources. It all works now. I am new to IntelliJ and totally unimpressed but how easy it is to get it into an unstable state.

Comment: You need to close intellij, delete the .idea folder (probably a hidden file); then open the folder again in intellij - it will reinitialize the intelli project based off of the maven / grade config.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried almost everything suggested in the answers here, but nothing worked for me.

After an hour of just trying to run my application, I noticed that my project's path included non-ASCII characters (Arabic characters). After I moved my project to a path with no non-ASCII characters, it executed just fine.

Comment: The same for me, even in Idea 2022 Ultimate. There was actually a warning sign: It refused to open the directory while pasting the path to the Open dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Invalidating cache didn't work.

I edited the main class java file with a dummy change and ran it. It worked.

Comment: this worked, simple fix

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem seemed to be related to upgrading IntelliJ. When I did this I overwrote the files from the old IntelliJ with the files from the new IntelliJ (2017 community to 2018 community). After that all of my projects were broken. I tried everything in this thread and none of them worked. I tried upgrading gradle to the latest version (4 to 4.8) and that didn't work. The only thing that worked for me was deleting the entire IntelliJ folder and reinstalling it. All of my projects worked after that.

Comment: It seems this actually it. I use portable intellij so I renamed the main folder like from `idea\bin` to be `idea_old\bin` and renamed the settings folder in `%user%\username` which is `.IntelliJIdea2018.2` to be `.IntelliJIdea2018.2_old` then re-extracted intellij zip file to start using it as fresh new portable version (This is version 2018.2.1) with Spring Boot app of multiple separated modules (not linked in single parent pom.xml) each is spring boot app with its own pom.xml and voila !!! All works, target folder created, compiling before running through spring boot dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IntelliJ with Spring and my main class is wrapped in a JAR. 
I had to mark the 'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope' in the Run/Debug configuration dialog

Answer (score 2):

Goto File-> Invalidate Caches and Restart .
Else delete rm -rf .idea *.iml
and restart InteliJ

Answer (score 2):

for me deleting .idea file in your project directory worked fine! close the ide ,
delete the .idea in your project  , open the project build and load !

Answer (score 1):

For me - i tried few of the options above, did not work. Then i just renamed my Application class and that probably forced intelliJ to build a fresh jar and error message started to change. Then i renamed it back and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the directory as a source directory. Opened via Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S

[image]

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

modules.xml with wrong content, I don't know what's matter  with my IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

I inherited a bunch of .JAVA files from elsewhere and couldn't figure out how to get them to work in any IDE. Ultimately I had to go to the command line where the Main.JAVA file was and run `javac Main.java`.  This created a bunch of .CLASS files.  The IDE's were then able to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using **Scala/SBT**. IntelliJ could not find the main class, even though everything was set up correctly.
My solution: delete the `<user>/.sbt/<version>/plugins/target` folder, then restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would have specified a wrong package and the package hierarchy would not be right. Look below

[image]

The ide would highlight the wrong path in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can check here is the actual command that is being passed to the JVM and make sure it looks OK. Scroll to the top of your Run console, it should be the first line.

**Spaces in your Run Configuration VM Options field** will malform the app startup command and can **result in this error message**

```
-DsomeArgument="arg with space must be quoted"
```

Answer (score 1):

We are at File/Project Structure..
Answer might be:

**Folder indicated as "content root" needs a child folder where the code is.** 
Plus find the button that marks code as excluded and not. 
Not to be confused with tickbox that states excluded without telling in what phase and what**
Is it compiler exclude or runtime exclude? You are doomed to test and lot.
So no that tickbox but icons and colors.

As an idea we need to crack how it was originally thought to work. They never got it to work in first place and started add things in premature codaculation style.
It has been so many years and you cannot expect any improvement.
But as cure we can hack out some way to get it right every time.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Kotlin but am guessing the problem is the same.  I would start a project, create a single file and add main to it and the IDE couldn't find the main.
I tried the things in this list and none worked.  I finally mentioned my frustration on one of the IntelliJ pages and was contacted.  Of course, it worked fine for IntelliJ.  After a couple of days back and forth, I noticed that the highlight function wasn't working and mentioned that.  It turned out something was wrong with the IDE settings.  I still don't know specifically what was wrong but the fix in my case was to reset the IDE settings.  File->Manage IDE Settings->Restore Default settings.
After this, the green triangle start icon became visible to the left of my main function and things continued to work normally for subsequent projects.
Thanks to Konstantin at JetBrain's support for his patience.

Answer (score 1):

1. choose maven as the type while creating project
   (do not check create from archetype checkbox)
2. Inside Project explorer, right click on java under main under src
3. choose new class
4. complete the class with public static void main
5. choose run from run menu

[image: intellij option to create a new java class]

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything, no luck. Finally, the simple solution that worked for me (on a Mac) was:

- while the project is open, go to the finder and move the src directory out of the project folder. IntelliJ realizes that the src is not there any more, and updates itself.
- with the project still open, move the src directory back in place. IntelliJ updates its project configuration, and at this point everything works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Right-click the folder where your class is in >> down you'll see an option "Mark Directory As..." Then you mark it as Source root.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Brad Turek's solution... One of the default IntelliJ Java project templates expects a file called Main defining the *class Main* and *main()* method entry point. If the method is contained in another file (and class), change the **Run** configuration:

[Run Configuration Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7R2t.jpg)

1. With the project open in IntelliJ, use the **Run:Edit Configurations...**
   menu to open the build configuration window.
2. If the entry for **Main class** doesn't list the name of your file containing the class exposing the
   *main()* entry method, enter the correct file name. (The configuration in the image is wrong, which is why it's red in the configuration panel.)
3. My *main()* entry method is in the class (and file) *ScrabbleTest*. So changing **Main class:** to *ScrabbleTest* fixes the runtime error.

As others have noted you have to **ReBuild** using the new configuration. I am using a package, but that doesn't seem to make a difference IME. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the module's build.gradle the mainClassName assignment must state the fully qualified class name, ie.  as specified as the package name in the main class' source code file.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-build the project (CTRL+F9) and double check (Edit Configurations) if you have a properly set Main class, and module (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is go to the backed folder in command line, where the root folder of the project. You should  have SBT installed in your machine.

If you have sbt installed, please run the command "sbt package", this will recompile the project if it success, come back to the intelliJ it will work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to an answer, eve if it is right, try to explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had (relatively) long vm arguments configured. Converting these arguments (whenever possible) to environment variables fixed the issue for me

Comment: You can't have spaces in your VM options unless you put "quotes" around the args

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the application runs well when code initially was under /src directory under the project. Later I added /main/java directory after the /src, then "Could not find or load main class ..." error happened. At that time you couldn't add /src/main/java/YourMain.java to the run configuration. What I did was to remove the run configuration, then right click the project->Open Module Settings (or F4 after click the Project panel)->Project Settings->Modules delete (x) the old Content Root and + Add Content Root, choose /src/main/java. Rebuild the project and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is a maven project, I ***Reimported maven*** (right click on ***pom.xml*** file and click ***Reimport***) that's it worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your project name and full directory name, see if contain any "**un-English**" words(like **Asian words**), sometimes this could be the fault. Rename the project name or project path contains such words and reopen it might work.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it helped to remove the lines build.gradle

*compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '8.2.0.jre11'*

I don't know why this happens, but after adding the specified library, the compiled jar stops working

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem and solved it by:

- Closing all IDEA windows
- Delete `C:/Userz/xx/.IdeaIC2019.3` folder
- Reopen IDEA

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle try rebuilding the project by the command from the command line:

```sh
gradle clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue when I went to "Edit configurations" -> "Modify options" and checked the "Do not build before run" option, as I use IntelliJ for short programming problems and I don't want it to run the build every time.

What I instead did is to assign a shortcut that runs the build process (only for the first time after a class is created), which fixes the error and then another convenient shortcut to "Run context configuration" that successfully runs the main method in whichever class is currently in focus.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out almost every suggestion in this tread I was still out off luck. Tried them on two different machines. Consulted an experienced colleague.

And finally: A solution to my problem, and probably the cause of the isssue:

**One of the folder names contained a forward slash on my Macs** *that's it*

(We used a (deeply) nested folder structure on a shared drive; and my colleague works on Windows and doesn't have an issue with the forward slash in the path)

NOTE: while I wanted to supply my answer here on stackoverflow in this thread, I got a 'warning' from stackoverflow that there where already more than 30 answers. But he, to no avail for me. And because it's a thread that dates from 2012 and is still active in 2023 with so many answers (and cause's of the same problem). I decided to add my fifty cents here as well. Hope it helps and saves somebody's time!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.build` folder and restart IntellJ IDE.

Answer (score 0):

- Go in Run/Debug Configuration panel.
- Below "Build and Run" make sur the given mainClass name is correct and edit it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No-brainer straightforward answer for Windows

Delete the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.3` folder. The folder is present inside `AppData` folder, which can be navigated from `C:\` and then `Users`, current user and there you can see the `AppData` folder.

```
Close all IDEA windows
Delete C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.3
Reopen IDEA
```

After deleting the `IdeaIC2023.3` folder, and re-opening `IntelliJ` it starts to re-structure the project, and the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

remove any README.md files or files with .md extensions from your project

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps

1. Go to run
2. Go to edit configurations
3. Click the green colored + sign in top left corner
4. Select the type you are working, for instance "Applications"
5. Now enter the name of the class which you want to run instead of unnamed
6. Do the same where it is written Main class,just below it.

Yippee....your code will run:)

Answer (score -1):

If the class which has the **main** method is extending/implementing another class/interface then it will not find the main class. Change the signature and it should work.

I had the same problem tried almost every answer from this thread non of them worked. Then this worked for me.