# How can I run Java JAR created from Intellij from command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) SO post and followed the steps but still I am unable to run it.

I tried running it as follows

```
Directory_where_jar_is_located $ java -jar Main.java
Error: Unable to access jarfile IcerbergRun
Directory_where_jar_is_located$ java -jar ProjectName.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class IcebergRun
```

What needs to be done after this? What are those dependencies? Also, I am sharing my pom.xml that has some bunch of libraries that are required for my project.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>SparkIceberg</groupId>
<artifactId>SparkTut</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <!--<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core" level="OFF" />-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.417</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-spark</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-data</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-parquet</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Netflix.iceberg</groupId>
        <artifactId>iceberg-orc</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-column</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891. If it doesn't help, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's usually `Directory_where_jar_is_located $ java -jar jar_file_name.jar`

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried the above question but I did not understand some stuff. As requested, I added some more info by editing my question. Please let me know further.

Comment: @Atihska it looks like you have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303815/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: How do you see what's inside JAR? I tried default Jar utility that gets in Mac with Java installation that didn't work. Also, I am not sure if my dependencies are being build inside JAR. How do you make sure about some external dependencies.

Comment: @Atihska jar is basically a ZIP, so you can use any archive manager to browse inside, or just unpack it to see.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Tried that too but on uncompressing I am getting `SparkTut.zip.cpgz` created. Tried on terminal using unzip and its unzipping.

Comment: @Atihska https://askubuntu.com/questions/239407/using-terminal-to-open-a-file-within-a-jar-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181113/discussion-between-atihska-and-crazycoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not sure why my IntelliJ produced JAR was unable to execute and getting `Could not load main class` so I tried my entire java project on command line and generated the JAR that worked for me.

Here are the steps:

**1. Install maven on ec2** 
https://gist.github.com/sebsto/19b99f1fa1f32cae5d00

```
$sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
$sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
$sudo yum install -y apache-maven
$mvn —version
```

**2. Install the following as well**

```
$sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
$yum install zip
```

**3. Do this to create maven project** 
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

```
$mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.package.name -DartifactId=java-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

**4. Edit code files and pom.xml. You can open the project in IntelliJ and edit.**

**5. MAVEN BUILD: Run from root dir of your java project**

```
java-project$mvn package or mvn clean package
```

**6. Remove these files created after build**

https://gist.github.com/hkhamm/88923412992d284580ea

```
java-project$zip -d target/iceberg-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA META-INF/*.SF
```

**7. Run JAR**

```
java-project$java -cp target/java-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.project.name.App
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Test project in java and built and executed the jar.

Initially the structure of project looked as shown below. The `out` directory contains only production directory. 
[image: Initial]

Now click on File-> Project Structure->Artifacts. Click on `+` sign next to left navigation pane in the upper left corner.

[image]

Now click on `+` sign and select Jar->from module with dependencies.... A dialog box will appear as shown below:

[image]

Now select the `Main Class` and select the `radio button` in front of `extract to the target JAR` and click `OK`. You will see the following [image]:

Check the `Include in project build checkbox` and click `Apply->Ok`.

[image]

Click on `Build->Build Project`. Now you can see that `out directory` has `artifacts sub-directory` which will have corresponding jar

[image]

Now on the terminal in `intelliJ` go inside directory where jar is present and execute the command `java -jar JAR_NAME.jar` and you can see that main function is executed.

Comment: Still unable to run it. I get `Error: Could not find or load main class IcebergRun`

Comment: Did you mention your main class in dialog box appear after clicking on `+` sign? Also please check do you have a class with `main function`?

Comment: @Atihska I build a jar without having main function inside any  class. When i execute the jar I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class
`.

Comment: Yes I have a class with. main function and I specified my main after clicking `+`. Please check my edits.

Comment: @Atihska look into solutions shared in https://stackoverflow.com/q/10654120/6407858

Comment: Not able to make it work still. I checked that my Main class exists. Using  `$ jar tf IcebergJava.jar | grep Main`, I get 
`com/example/Main.class`. But still getting could not find or load main class com.example.Main. This means its reading the manifest file.