# Could not find or load main class- Error after Building Artifact in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, artifact

I am developing a maven project and I am facing an error of **Could not find or load main class** after building an artifact in intellij ,and this has happened after adding google-oauth-client-jetty dependency ,more so this javax.servlet 3.0.0.v201112011016.jar is causing the problem because as soon as i remove this from the artifact my project runs, but this jar is required so that i can redirect the user to gmail login page, can anyone help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654120/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-intellij-ide Can you check this out? Provided you are facing the similar kind of issue.

Comment: it's not sufficient detail to get you an answer. Please share Configuration details of intellij under Run menu. Also, share what you have got inside

Comment: What do you want to know in specific? @VinayPrajapati

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin this solution isn't working for me ,i tried it out