# Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter after update Intellij IDE to 2021.1

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit4

I updated my Intellij IDE to:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-211.6693.111, built
> on April 6, 2021

I have started to get this message after unit tests finishing since I updated Intellij IDE:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter

Tests pass but Intelij shows this message. I tried to fix it and found this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911888/11926338). I closed IDE and removed `.idea` folder in my project. After that, I opened Project and rebuilt it. After that I started to get this error:

> Error running 'package.with.tests in my-app': Command line is too
> long. Shorten command line for package.with.tests in my-app or also
> for JUnit default configuration?

After googling I found solution:

[image]

I chouse this option and I returned to first exception:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter

These are some configs of my IDE:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the code sample where you experience the issue. And the dependencies of the project. Thank you

Comment: @Olga Klisho No. It is a large multimodule project with private code.